# Blender 2.6 Console in window

Tags: python, windows, blender-2.61

I want to refresh my Python skill in Blender since it been a while. However, when I open Blender the console window does not open anymore. Also, when I go to the console and run the scripts from the text editor nothing shows up on the console.
I do not want to save this file but I do want feedback from the console.

How do I get feedback with the Blender 2.6. I have a PC, not a Mac.

Comment: You don’t say what OS. This sort of thing is probably easier on Linux, where you can either run Blender from a command-line window and see error/debug messages there, or look in your ~/.xsession-errors file if running it from a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to help toggle system console.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.78 on Windows, go to **Window -> Toggle System Console**.